# SQL Filter by Excluding Specific String

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am looking to run my query (below) by displaying latest value  for `"DATA_POINT_UPLOAD_DATA"."VALUE"` , except `'READY'`.  Currently, it displays all `'READY'` values, however, I want to do the opposite by displaying any values up to the time of execution except `'READY'`.

Here is my current query:

```
select  "DATA_POINT_UPLOAD_DATA"."LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP" as "TIMESTAMP",
               "DATA_POINT_UPLOAD_DATA"."VALUE" as "COMMENTS"
 from   "DB"."COMPONENT" "COMPONENT",
    "DB"."COMPONENT_DATA_POINT" "COMPONENT_DATA_POINT",
    "DB"."DATA_POINT_UPLOAD_DATA" "DATA_POINT_UPLOAD_DATA" 
 where   "COMPONENT_DATA_POINT"."ID"="DATA_POINT_UPLOAD_DATA"."COMPONENT_DATA_POINT_ID"
 and     "COMPONENT"."ID"="COMPONENT_DATA_POINT"."COMPONENT_ID"
  and    "DATA_POINT_UPLOAD_DATA"."VALUE" ='READY' 
   and   "DATA_POINT_UPLOAD_DATA"."LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP" between ('01-JUN-17') and ('30-JUN-17') 
   and   "COMPONENT_DATA_POINT"."NAME" ='StateOfItem' 
   and   "COMPONENT"."SITE_ID" in('abc123');
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One small change to this, `and    "DATA_POINT_UPLOAD_DATA"."VALUE" ='READY' ` should do the trick.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my original post.  I want it to not populate over 5,500 results...but only the latest as of execution time.

Comment: Do you want the single row or all rows before READY? Are there multiple READYs?

Comment: Any non-READY rows, but the latest for each type.

Comment: Latest per `type` is a new requirement. There is no `type` column in your query, though. So what type are you referring to? Do you mean per `VALUE`?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Correct, per 'VALUE'

Comment: Okay, I've posted a new answer on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking for the latest record per `VALUE` now. You are only selecting `VALUE` and `LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP`, however. So what you are asking is merely the maximum `LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP` per `VALUE`. In SQL this translates to `MAX(last_updated_timestamp)` with `GROUP BY value`.

```
Select  
  max(last_updated_timestamp) as "timestamp",
  value as comments
From db.data_point_upload_data
Where value <> 'READY' 
and last_updated_timestamp between '2017-06-01' and '2017-06-30'
and cdp_id in
(
  select id
  from db.component_data_point
  where name = 'StateOfItem'
  and component_id in (select id from db.component where site_id = 'abc123')
)
Group by value;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `WHERE` clause you have this: `"DATA_POINT_UPLOAD_DATA"."VALUE" ='READY'`. That means you want to display the rows where DATA_POINT_UPLOAD_DATA has the value 'READY'.

Change your query and instead of using `=` try using `!=` or `<>`.

```
SELECT "DATA_POINT_UPLOAD_DATA"."LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP" AS "TIMESTAMP",
  "DATA_POINT_UPLOAD_DATA"."VALUE"                       AS "COMMENTS"
FROM "DB"."COMPONENT" "COMPONENT",
  "DB"."COMPONENT_DATA_POINT" "COMPONENT_DATA_POINT",
  "DB"."DATA_POINT_UPLOAD_DATA" "DATA_POINT_UPLOAD_DATA"
WHERE "COMPONENT_DATA_POINT"."ID"    ="DATA_POINT_UPLOAD_DATA"."COMPONENT_DATA_POINT_ID"
AND "COMPONENT"."ID"                 ="COMPONENT_DATA_POINT"."COMPONENT_ID"
AND "DATA_POINT_UPLOAD_DATA"."VALUE" !='READY'
AND "DATA_POINT_UPLOAD_DATA"."LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP" BETWEEN ('01-JUN-17') AND ('30-JUN-17')
AND "COMPONENT_DATA_POINT"."NAME" ='StateOfItem'
AND "COMPONENT"."SITE_ID"        IN('abc123');
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited my original post.  I want it to not populate over 5,500 results...but only the latest as of execution time.

Comment: You mean you want to display the latest value before 'READY'?

Comment: Well, more like the latest value (other than READY).  If I use the != it displays all other values, which is half of the solution, but then I want to only see the latest of those values.

Comment: Do you have a row for every state in your table?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say, but that is a horrible query. Almost only upper case so as to minimize readability, table alias names that are no alias names, a join syntax that was made redundant twentyfive years ago, date string literals that only work in certain language settings, and unnecessary joins.

Then you select records with `value = 'READY'` and say that you want records that are **not** 'READY'. Well, then: `WHERE NOT value = 'READY'` or simply `WHERE value <> 'READY'`.

Here is the altered query:

```
Select  
  last_updated_timestamp as "timestamp",
  value as comments
From db.data_point_upload_data
Where value <> 'READY' 
and last_updated_timestamp between '2017-06-01' and '2017-06-30'
and cdp_id in
(
  select id
  from db.component_data_point
  where name = 'StateOfItem'
  and component_id in (select id from db.component where site_id = 'abc123')
);
```

If you only want to see the latest n rows, then `order by last_updated_timestamp desc limit <n>`.

Comment: Your query outputs the same as mine....this still doesn't answer what I am looking for.  Thanks.

Comment: You have `= 'READY'`, I have `<> 'READY'`. I don't see how the two queries can return the same rows.

Comment: Yeah, I changed it to != on my query to exclude...and that then outputs the same as yours.